# How to share a vault between separate ansible project

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have 3 separate ansible project. Problem is, they all have their own vault, and I have to redefine some variable in common in all these vaults and change the variable everywhere every time.

Is it a way to share a vault between ansible projects ?

EDIT : I already considered to regroup all the projets in 1 but they are very different and I don't like this solution

Comment: Why wouldn't you have all of these in the same project? In that case, you'd have the same vault in one location, and could use different host groups to specify what gets run on which host. You'd have one host group `cloud`, one `wiki` and one `sso` - that's the way I use Ansible in this case.

Comment: Yes we are considering this option

Comment: @amdev: Next option would be to link the common vault to each project's directory.

Comment: "put on hold as too broad" Are ou kidding me ? "Is there a way to share a vault between ansible projets" Is to broad ?